# system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! (parcel size = 108) in Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Emulator and I am not sending any data with bundle. Even if all the application are closed, it keeps showing up.

the emulator spec is like this:

10.4 inch
2000x1200
hdpi
Android S(Android 12.0 arm64-v8a)
Landscape

Is there any solution to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: which operating system are you on?

Comment: I am using the emulator on Android Studio(MacOS)

Answer (score 2):

I met this error too. After I get back from a nap at noon, this bug occurred, these alarm messages keeps appearing on the simulator.

I tried to delete my app, close Android Studio, restart my computer. Nothing worked.

At last, I have to delete this device from "Device Manager", and create a new one, then everything is fine. Don't know why, but it works for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32925852)